# Is `providers: [ MyService ]` the same as `providers: [{ provide: MyComponent, useClass: MyComponent }]`

Tags: angular, angular2-injection

I'm reading the `ng-book` on angular 2 revision 47 page 250 and there is the following passage:

> When we put the class itself into the list of providers like this:
>
> ```
> providers: [ MyService ]
> ```
>
> That is telling Angular that we want to provide a singleton instance of MyService whenever MyService is
>   injected. Because this pattern is so common, the class by itself is
>   shorthand notation for the following, equivalent configuration:
>
> ```
> providers: [
>     { provide: MyComponent, useClass: MyComponent }
> ]
> ```

Is it a typo and what is meant should be:

```
providers: [
    { provide: MyService, useClass: MyService }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typo, since you can't use components as Providers, here's the [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#the-provider-class-_andprovidefn-)

> The Provider class and provide object literal We wrote the providers
>   array like this:
>
> ```
> providers: [Logger]
> ```
>
> This is actually a shorthand expression
>   for a provider registration using a provider object literal with two
>   properties:
>
> ```
> [{ provide: Logger, useClass: Logger }]
> ```
>
> The first is the token that
>   serves as the key for both locating a dependency value and registering
>   the provider.
>
> The second is a provider definition object, which we can think of as a
>   recipe for creating the dependency value. There are many ways to
>   create dependency values ... and many ways to write a recipe

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the same.
When the type passed to `provide` and `useClass` is the same, then it's equivalent to just pass the `type`.

Just a hint. Providing a component (`MyComponent`) usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: so it's most likely a typo?

Comment: Ok, now I get what you mean. Yes, I'm sure `MyComponent` instead of `MyService` is a typo.

Comment: ok, thanks, just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something else

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of them are same.
When you write providers: [MyService] angular will expand this into [{ provide: MyService, useClass: MyService}] where the first parameter **provide: MyService** will
work as a Dependency injection token that will work as a key to locate "MyService"
and the second parameter **useClass: MyService** it will create dependency from the
existing service class MyService